# How do I create a VS Extension without adding UI?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2015 extension that adds messages to the Error List window. It needs no new UI. My code runs correctly if used in a tool window or menu item, but adding UI just for this feels like a sloppy workaround to obtain an `IServiceProvider`.

**How can my code run and obtain an `IServiceProvider` without adding any UI elements?**

Comment: From where do you want to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Package` class is an `IServiceProvider`; you can just call its `GetService` method.

If you're in a MEF class, you can instead simply import `SVsServiceProvider`.

For more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-11-10/extending-visual-studio-part-2-core-concepts/).

Comment: This wasn't quite enough to make a package load with no UI. Visual Studio delays initializing extensions until the package UI is used. Thus it is necessary to add the [`ProvideAutoLoad` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx) to the package class.